# How can I make a function that takes in a parameter and when executed, it alerts whatever you give the function?

Tags: javascript

I am in a coding bootcamp prep class and I did not pass my first quiz because i did not understand functions. I talked to my mentor about the problem that get me stuck, he said it does not remember the problem word by word but it was

"It is basically writing a function that takes a parameter and when executed it alerts whatever you give the function"

I guess what got me stuck was when I writing the function when I got to the part

```
var varName = function(parameter){ alert()}
```

I was not too sure what to put in the `alert()`, I keep thinking it was supposed to take in a string so when it actually alerts, it will display something a sentence to tell the user.

Comment: `var varName = function(parameter){ alert(parameter)}` you can call it by `varName('Something')`; this will alert something

Comment: I recommend reading the docs for `alert()` if you haven't yet.  It's very short :) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Comment: I recommend reading the docs for [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) if you haven't yet. It's not that short, but very important. Any JavaScript tutorial will also quickly introduce you to functions. For example, see this [Mozilla intro](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Functions). StackOverflow is not a very good match for this kind of question about extremely basic language features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var varName = function(parameter){ alert(parameter)}
```

Thats the slight edit from your attempt. Rest is fine.

call it like varName("Hello World")

SEE WORKING SNIPPET BELOW:

```js
var varName = function(parameter) {
  alert(parameter);
}
varName("Hello World");
```

Have a look at the MDN Docs for [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert).

Comment: Because it's their prerogative

Comment: @FrankerZ SO itself recommends you to leave a comment while downvoting. It would be definitely productive to the community. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: This is a completely valid answer and should not be downvoted. Upvoted to keep this in the positive at least.

Answer (score -1):

So in basics a function is a set of code that can be re-used and executed by calling the function directly.

For simplicity sakes [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) is a function and has the parameter `message`.

```
window.alert(message);
```

Window is optional as the `alert` method is part of the window scope.

So to create a function that takes a paramater can be a simple as

```
function myAlert(message) {
    alert(message);
}

myAlert('test message');
```

The first block defines the function as seen by `function xx(...)`. The function when executed accepts the paramter `message`. Then this message is simply passed to the `alert(...)` function.

Answer (score -1):

```
var saySomething = function(message) { alert(message); }
saySomething('hello world')
```

You're creating a function, a function in JavaScript is simply an encapsulation of code to which you can pass arguments. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Should use `var` keyword. Your example creates a global variable. Hopefully the teacher is using strict mode from day one, this won't work in strict mode.